# Android App crashes when push is received and app is closed

Tags: android, cordova, nullpointerexception, push, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an Android & iOS App with cordova. Current Version there is 2.2.0. I've got the following Java code to show the Push Notification:

```
private void putNotification(String title, String message){
        try{
            Log.w("Push", "putNotification");
            MainActivity context = MainActivity.getAppContext();
            Log.w("Push", "context is set");

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Log.w("Push", "notificationManager is set");
                Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, title, System.currentTimeMillis());
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                note.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pendingIntent);
                note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notificationManager.notify(0, note);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.w("Push failed", e); 
        }
    }
```

When the app is running in the background the code works perfectly fine. But If the app is fully closed, I'm getting the following LogCat Errors, and no push is shown:

```
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push(3276): putNotification
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push(3276): context is set
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push failed(3276): java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push failed(3276):   at ch.seika.lakers.GCMIntentService.putNotification(GCMIntentService.java:105)
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push failed(3276):   at ch.seika.lakers.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:46)
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push failed(3276):   at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push failed(3276):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push failed(3276):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push failed(3276):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 09-23 16:30:24.725: W/Push failed(3276):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Line 105 is the following:
`NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

I really can't say where the Null Pointer Exception is coming from, so any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `context` is `null` because `MainActivity.getAppContext();` returns `null` ... you have to learn about Activity lifecycle ... **edit:** change `putNotification(String title, String message)` to `putNotification(Context context, String title, String message)` and use `context` from method arguments ... as context you can pass `Service`, too

Comment: Hint: `context` is null.

Comment: @Selvin: Wow, simple as that. Thanks very much! If you make this an answer you get the reputation for it, too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

in your code java.lang.NullPointerException exception occurs due to null context..

so,use context which is passed in onMessage method

```
 protected void onMessage(final Context context, Intent intent)
```

use this context in your GCMIntentService class