# apache cordova app crashes after receiving parse.com push notification

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, parse-platform

I want to add parse.com push notification service to my Cordova app. I've read parse.com quick start guide and I've placed SDK file in the libs folder. after that I've added the codes to main java file and AndroidManifest.xml. the app working correctly. parse.com can receive my device token and I can send push notification to the device but after two or three push notification the app will crash.

the error message in the catlog is this:

```
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/com.parse.PushService(28735): The Parse push service cannot start because Parse.initialize has not yet been called. If you call Parse.initialize from an Activity's onCreate, that call should instead be in the Application.onCreate. Be sure your Application class is registered in your AndroidManifest.xml with the android:name property of your <application> tag.
05-07 02:08:25.185: D/AndroidRuntime(28735): Shutting down VM
05-07 02:08:25.185: W/dalvikvm(28735): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b0de48)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735): Process: ir.wedesign.pushapp, PID: 28735
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.parse.PushService@42b596a8 with Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=ir.wedesign.pushapp cmp=ir.wedesign.pushapp/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2726)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:557)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.parse.Parse.getApplicationContext(Parse.java:165)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getContext(ManifestInfo.java:221)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageManager(ManifestInfo.java:229)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageInfo(ManifestInfo.java:240)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.deviceSupportsGcm(ManifestInfo.java:325)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPushType(ManifestInfo.java:109)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at com.parse.PushService.onStartCommand(PushService.java:377)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2709)
05-07 02:08:25.185: E/AndroidRuntime(28735):    ... 10 more
```

this is my main java file:

```
/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
 */

package ir.wedesign.pushapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class PushApp extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        Parse.initialize(this, "xJK9ZA0Dtsjd8RwoNUUsIHPXzMRbmcxXGWqiw", "19g9eUKjLjlUdogHEXStUABNcvy2rA6azb5mXy");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, PushApp.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    }
}
```

and my manifest.xml file is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="ir.wedesign.pushapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="ir.wedesign.pushapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ir.wedesign.pushapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">   
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="PushApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="ir.wedesign.pushapp" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

I've searched and it seems that many developers have exactly the same problem. I've found two topics in parse.com help forum:
https://www.parse.com/questions/app-crashes-after-after-screen-unlock
https://www.parse.com/questions/cannot-send-push-to-android-after-app-is-closed-until-screen-unlock
and this one here:
[Android App crashes when push is received and app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962138/android-app-crashes-when-push-is-received-and-app-is-closed)

but the solutions isn't clear for someone that don't know java. How can I change my AndroidManifest.xml and main java file to make it work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Parse push service cannot start because Parse.initialize has not yet been called. 
>   If you call Parse.initialize from an Activity's onCreate, that call should instead be in the Application.onCreate. 
>   Be sure your Application class is registered in your AndroidManifest.xml with the android:name property of your  tag.

Try to seperate Activity and Application, create a new class file e.g. MainApplication.

PushApp.java:

```
public class PushApp extends CordovaActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "xJK9ZA0Dtsjd8RwoNUUsIHPXzMRbmcxXGWqiw", "19g9eUKjLjlUdogHEXStUABNcvy2rA6azb5mXy");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, PushApp.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

and change:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="PushApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

to:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MainApplication" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

now you should also receive push notifications when app is closed / screen is locked

Answer (score 1):

check your manifest.xml if you named the `<application>` as `android:name="MainApplication"`

and the `<activity>` as `android:name="PushApp"`